# jquery click "first div hide second show"

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-selectors, hide, show

I have 6 divs with different info and I need to change them all at the same time on the "next" button click, I found jquery function, but the problem is that I cant use more than one div (in jq function, because function stops working), so I duplicated 6 times, maybe there is some issue?

For the first div:

```
        $(".arrow_right").click(function(){
            if ($(".contestant_1 div:visible").next().length != 0)
                $(".contestant_1 div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
            else {
                $(".contestant_1 div:visible").hide();
                $(".contestant_1 div:first").show();
            }
            return false;
        });

        $(".arrow_left").click(function(){
            if ($(".contestant_1 div:visible").prev().length != 0)
                $(".contestant_1 div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
            else {
                $(".contestant_1 div:visible").hide();
                $(".contestant_1 div:last").show();
            }
            return false;
        });
```

5 more(about 150lines)...

Thank you!

Comment: is it is like you need to hide all odd number of div's and show all even div's?

Comment: Create a JSFiddle maybe? Seeing the HTML and CSS would help quite a bit.

Comment: not working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hsJbu/777/
should change 1 and 11 to 2 and 22 and etc...

Comment: What do you mean you can't use more than one div?  There are a number of ways to do what you're trying to do with jQuery .show and .hide, or binding visibility with knockout.js.  I don't mind giving you an example of the binding if you are allowed or willing to use knockout, it would be very easy.

Comment: That if I add extra class here: 
$(".contestant_1 div:visible").next().length != 0)   >> class added >> $(".contestant_1, .contestant_2 div:visible").next().length != 0)....... script stops working, so I should look for other way to do this?